# blogger posts only shows 3 and not 10

Tags: post

"Hello, I'm experiencing an issue with my recipe blog on Blogger. Regardless of the theme I choose, my main page consistently displays only three posts, even though I've adjusted the settings to show 10. I've double-checked all the configurations, but the problem persists. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to resolve this and get all 10 posts to show on the main page?"

change all settings in the blogger setup

Answer (score 0):

To double check:

**Check your settings:** Go to Blogger >> Your blog >> Layout >> Look for ‘Blog Posts’ and click on ‘edit’. Change it to any number you want.

**Number of Posts section:** Head to the Number of Posts section of your Blogger dashboard that is located at Settings>>Post and Comment and change the number of post from 1 to the desired number.

If these steps don’t resolve the issue, you might want to contact Blogger via the Feedback button on the Blogger Dashboard.